# How to nest multiple groupby with loadash/javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, lodash

Thank you in advance to whoever can help me. I am trying to display data using SectionList in React Native. I have written my code below displaying what I am trying to accomplish. A regular javascript solution will work. I want the data to first be grouped together by date, and inside of that date, I need them grouped by location.

It's important that it has a title and data key
I have data in this format:

```
[ { game_id: 1171,
    date: '2018-11-17',
    location: 'Plaza'
   },
  { game_id: 1189,
    date: '2018-11-17',
    location: 'Field - Kickball'
   },
   { game_id: 1489,
    date: '2018-11-16',
    location: 'Field - Kickball'
   },
   { game_id: 1488,
    date: '2018-11-16',
    location: 'Field - Soccer'
   }
]
```

I need the output to show:

```
data = [{
    title: "2018-11-17",
    data: [{
            title: "Field - Kickball",
            data: [{
                game_id: 1189,
                date: '2018-11-17',
                location: 'Field - Kickball'
            }]
        },
        {
            title: "Plaza",
            data: [{
                game_id: 1171,
                date: '2018-11-17',
                location: 'Plaza'
            }]
        }
    ]
    },
    {
        title: "2018-11-16",
        data: [{
                title: "Field - Kickball",
                data: [{
                    game_id: 1489,
                    date: '2018-11-16',
                    location: 'Field - Kickball'
                }]
            },
            {
                title: "Field - Soccer",
                data: [{
                    game_id: 1488,
                    date: '2018-11-16',
                    location: 'Field - Soccer'
                }]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I have already tried this

```
const games = [data here]
var groups = _(games)
.groupBy(x => x.date)
        .map(value => {
            return _.groupBy(value, 'location')
            .map(({key, value}) => ({title: key, data: value}))
        })

        .map((value, key) => {
            return ({title: value[Object.keys(value)[0]][0].date, data: value})
        })
```

Comment: can you write the expected output as well?

Comment: The expected value is the code that starts with "I need the output to show:"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `reduce` like so:

```js
const data = [{game_id:1171,date:'2016-11-17T05:00:00.000Z',time:'08:00:00',category:'Ch B Coed',background:'#FFFF00',textcolor:'#000000',bold:0,sport:'Newcomb',location:'Plaza',text:'COL2 vs. USA1 1171'},{game_id:1189,date:'2016-11-17T05:00:00.000Z',time:'08:50:00',category:'Ch A Coed',background:'#FF33CC',textcolor:'#000000',bold:0,sport:'Kickball',location:'Field - Kickball',text:'COL1 vs. USA1 1189'},{game_id:1489,date:'2016-2-17T05:00:00.000Z',time:'04:50:00',category:'Ch B Coed',background:'#FF33CC',textcolor:'#000000',bold:0,sport:'Kickball',location:'Field - Kickball',text:'COL2 vs. USA3 1489'}];

const res = Object.values(data.reduce((acc, { date, ...rest }) => acc[date] ? { ...acc, [date]: { ...acc[date], data: acc[date].data.concat({ date, ...rest })} } : { ...acc, [date]: { title: date, data: [{ date, ...rest }] }}, {}));

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Comment: No worries @EyalAbadi, if my answer fixed your problem please accept it by clicking the grey tick mark to the left of my answer.

Comment: Yes it will - it'll collect `date` and all other properties into variables, then arrange them into `title` and `data`.

Comment: Sorry, I actually messed up the expected output. What I meant was inside each day, there would be another title and data all separated by fields. What I really needed was ```[
{title:"2016-11-17T05:00:00.000Z",data: [
    title:"Field - Kickball" data:{
     game_id: 1489,
     date: '2016-2-17T05:00:00.000Z',
     time: '04:50:00',
     category: 'Ch B Coed',
     background: '#FF33CC',
     textcolor: '#000000',
     bold: 0,
     sport: 'Kickball',
     location: 'Field - Kickball',
     text: 'COL2 vs. USA3 1489'
    },...```

Answer (score 0):

Pardon me if I am missing something but this to me it seems can be done in somewhat simpler manner via [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
let data = [{ game_id: 1171, date: '2016-11-17T05:00:00.000Z', time: '08:00:00', category: 'Ch B Coed', background: '#FFFF00', textcolor: '#000000', bold: 0, sport: 'Newcomb', location: 'Plaza', text: 'COL2 vs. USA1 1171' }, { game_id: 1189, date: '2016-11-17T05:00:00.000Z', time: '08:50:00', category: 'Ch A Coed', background: '#FF33CC', textcolor: '#000000', bold: 0, sport: 'Kickball', location: 'Field - Kickball', text: 'COL1 vs. USA1 1189' }, { game_id: 1489, date: '2016-2-17T05:00:00.000Z', time: '04:50:00', category: 'Ch B Coed', background: '#FF33CC', textcolor: '#000000', bold: 0, sport: 'Kickball', location: 'Field - Kickball', text: 'COL2 vs. USA3 1489' } ]

let result = data.reduce((r, c) => {
  r[c.date] = r[c.date] || {title: c.date, data: []}
  r[c.date].data = [...(r[c.date].data || []), c]
  return r
}, {})

console.log(Object.values(result))
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I actually messed up the intended output. Can you help me again?

Comment: Well you input is all over the place for that output. Can you format and make sure you input dates match your output groupings? You dates are off to be grouped the way you want. They have to match first to then be grouped by location etc.

Comment: I have updated the expected result! Thanks in advance! I've been pulling out my hairs trying to figure out a solution

Comment: I posted an answer in your other thread. It was better that way I guess since here you already have an accepted answer etc.